# Heroku: error running django migrations

Tags: django, heroku

I'm writing a django app that is currently deployed on heroku. The latest migrations I have made throw an error which I don't understand, see below.
This error does not appear locally, maybe that is because I use sqlite locally and postgres on heroku, but that is only a guess.
I generated the migration locally and pushed it.

I use django 1.10 and a virtual environment with python 2.7.

Here is my terminal ouput when I try to run the migration:

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ limitless-lake-59470... up, run.3202 (Free)
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, jobs, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying jobs.0015_auto_20161230_2039...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 204, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 495, in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py", line 117, in _alter_field
    new_db_params, strict,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 649, in _alter_field
    params,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 112, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: ""
```

Comment: "maybe that is because I use sqlite locally and postgres on heroku, but that is only a guess." very likely. sqlite dosen't enforce types. Postgresql does. Please post the mode in question

Comment: The whole models.py file is rather large and I don't know what causes the trouble. Anyways, **I fixed this** by clearing the whole db and applying the migrations from scratch. Don't know why this helped, but it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error disappeared after clearing the db and applying all migrations from scratch